# Standard counterexample in Hodge decomposition

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory

I am studying Hodge theory on complex manifolds; Höring's notes ([https://math.univ-cotedazur.fr/~hoering/hodge/hodge.pdf](https://math.univ-cotedazur.fr/%7Ehoering/hodge/hodge.pdf) p. 87) suggest, as an exercise (4.38) and I guess as a counterexample to Hodge decomposition when our manifold is not compact, that $ \mathbb{C}$ with standard Kähler structure doesn't admit a decomposition of its first cohomology group, in symbols $H^1(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}) \neq H^{1,0}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus H^{0,1}(\mathbb{C})$.
But shouldn't all these groups be equal to zero?

Comment: What makes you think that $H^{1,0}(\mathbb C)=0$?

Comment: Every (smooth) $(0,1)$-form on $\Bbb C$ is $\bar\partial$-closed. Is every such form equal to $\bar\partial g$ for some smooth $g$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that, in general, $H^{p,0}(X)=H^0(X,\Omega^p_X)$. Now $\Omega_\mathbb C^1$, the co-tangent bundle, is the trivial bundle of rank $1$ on $\mathbb C$, the holomorphic sections of which are just the holomorphic functions, of which there are plenty.